# SQL Get Most count value from a Group By

Tags: sql, distinct-values

I will explain clearly :
I have hockey stats in a table by position

Player 12 :

```
StatsID  /  PlayerID   / Position  / gamesPlayed / points  /  Season
 1      /     12      /  RW     /      40     /  32     / 2013-2014
 2      /     12     /  Def    /       1     /   1    / 2013-2014
```

So I want a query like this

```
Select PlayerID , Season , sum(gamesPlayed) as GP, sum(points) as pts , ???? from
MyPointTable GROUP BY PlayerID, SEASON
```

I want to replace my ???? that will gives me the position that the played play the most so he play 40 games like a RW . I can't count , I can't sum.

The SQL result is supposed to gives

```
ID , Season    , GP , pts, MostPosition
12 , 2013-2014 , 41 , 33 , RW
```

Thanks

Comment: What database are you on?

Comment: Did you have any luck with my answer?

Comment: It's SQL Server. @Brian Tyr to read about subquery, didn't get the time to test your answer. And finally I found something else. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

This works on PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT 
    PlayerID AS ID,
    Season,  
    subQuery.sqTotalGames AS GP, 
    subQuery.sqTotalPoints AS pts, 
    position AS MostPosition
FROM
    MyPointTable 
    INNER JOIN
        (
            SELECT 
                PlayerID as sqPlayerID, 
                MAX(gamesPlayed) as sqMaxGames, 
                SUM(gamesPlayed) as sqTotalGames, 
                SUM(points) AS sqTotalPoints 
            FROM 
                MyPointTable 
            GROUP by playerID
        ) subQuery 
            ON subQuery.sqMaxGames = gamesPlayed 
                AND subQuery.sqPlayerID = PlayerID;
```

Answer (score 0):

It it's Sql Server you may be able to use SQL Rank first to get the most played and then do your groupings

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176102.aspx

Comment: Thanks seems good, when I will have time to understand how the function Rank works, I will try it. Thanks !!